# Python: "'Nonetype' is not iteratable" without any iteration

Tags: python, iteration, runtime-error, hashtable, nonetype

I'm writing a program to form hash tables of different sizes with linear probing. In my ADT for the linear probing I have a function def insert ( ) which is called from my main script from the following function:

```
def insertHashTable(  loadNum, hashTable  ):
    i = 0
    while i < ((loadNum*size)-1):
        hashTable.insert(data[i],data[i])
        i = i + 1
    return hashTable
```

The error itself is from this function that is called from insertHashTable( )

```
def insert( self, key, value ):
    ( found, slot ) = self._findSlot( key ) #ERROR HERE
    if not found :
        self._table[slot] = _MapEntry( key, value ) #custom datatype
        self._count += 1
    return not found
```

I get the nonetype error on the second line of this code. Finally, _findSlot( ) is the following:

```
def _findSlot( self, key ):        
    startLoc = self._hash1( key )

    self.slotsAccessed += 1
    if self._table.__getitem__( startLoc ) == None:
        return (False, startLoc)

    else:
        c = 0
        while (c+startLoc) < (self._size -1):
            if self._table[startLoc+c] == None:
                return (False, startLoc+c) 
            elif self._table.__getitem__( startLoc ).key == key:
                return (True, startLoc+c) 
            c = c + 1
            self.slotsAccessed += c
```

I'm not sure why there would be such an error in the insertHashTable( ) function, seeing as there is no iteration happening with the key.

I do however know my hashtable has 'None' in every slot at initialization of the table, maybe there's some issue with that?

Comment: (c+startLoc) < (self._size -1) might be False in first iteration and you do not have a return case for it.  I suppose you didn't consider that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `_findSlot(self, key)` function can complete without a return statement. (Specifically, this will happen if your `while` condition becomes false and the loop finishes.) In that case, the function will return `None`. If you try and assign `(found, slot)` the value `None`, you get the error `Nonetype is not iterable`.

You probably need to figure out what your function is supposed to return in the case where it is currently returning `None`.